# How to stream rtsp output by crtmp server by inputing rtmp stream from fmle using webcam?

Tags: configuration, streaming, rtsp, rtmp

Can anybody suggest me on crtmpserver.lua configuration?

I setup crtmp server on AWS EC2 Ubuntu 12.04. after building deb package successfully.
I have successfully stream my Webcam stream using FMLE on my windows 7 machine, connected to my crtmp server,then played on website using JW Player.

Now i want to get RTSP stream from the same crtmp server using same RTMP input to play on mobile.I read crtmp server can stream both in RTMP and RTSP. Please guide me on confiuration of crtmpserver.lua to achieve this.

Also please let me know if i can use multibit encoding high bit rate for web and low for mobile streaming same webcam stream?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use ffmpeg (self compiled version) not apt. use the -f flv flag and outpu to rtmp://host/live(application)/camera(streamname-dynamic)